# SelectList Does not Select Specific Value

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have problem with my code.  I select a specific value using `SelectList` function but it seems it is not working.  Here is my code:

**Controller:**

```
Public IActionResult Index()
{
   myList.loanFrequency = new SelectList(lstLoanFrequency, "Id", "Value", 4);
}
```

**View:**

```html
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Loan Frequency</label>
        <select class="form-control" asp-for="loanContract.LoanFrequencyId" asp-items="@Model.loanFrequency" disabled></select>
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Upon registration to this loan you are set to a <b>Biweekly</b> because your payroll mostly computed and deducted every Biweekly day of the month.</small>
    </div>
```

And it seems it renders like this:

```html
<select class="form-control" disabled="" data-val="true" data-val-required="The LoanFrequencyId field is required." id="loanContract_LoanFrequencyId" name="loanContract.LoanFrequencyId">
<option value="1">Weekly</option>
<option value="2">Biweekly</option>
<option value="3">Semimonthly</option>
<option value="4">Monthly</option>//Not rendered in HTML
<option value="5">Bimonthly</option>
<option value="6">Quarterly</option>
<option value="7">Semiannually</option>
<option value="8">Annually</option>
</select>
```

And since I set the `SelectedValue` from SelectList method it should suppose to be render the item something like this:

```html
<select class="form-control" disabled="" data-val="true" data-val-required="The LoanFrequencyId field is required." id="loanContract_LoanFrequencyId" name="loanContract.LoanFrequencyId">
<option value="1">Weekly</option>
<option value="2">Biweekly</option>
<option value="3">Semimonthly</option>
<option value="4" selected>Monthly</option>//This should be rendered in the HTML
<option value="5">Bimonthly</option>
<option value="6">Quarterly</option>
<option value="7">Semiannually</option>
<option value="8">Annually</option>
</select>
```

How come that It didn't select a specific value? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You were told yesterday already, that you were using tags for old verison of ASP.NET MVC. [tag:asp.net] and [tag:asp.net-mvc] are for the **OLD ASP.NET MVC** webstack. Please use [tag:asp.net-core] and/or [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] when you have a question regarding ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tag Helper Confusion**

It's important to note that the `asp-for` tag helper is going to function very similar to some of the older MVC HTML Helpers, in that, it will handle binding a specific property within the View. As such, you'll need to ensure that it points to whatever property represents the "Frequency Id" that is present on your Loan instances.

The `asp-items` tag helper in this instance won't really need a value, as that will be set by the `asp-for` helper on its own. You'll just need to build a list of your frequencies and their corresponding identifiers, and then pass in a collection of Loan objects to your View and let the tag helpers take care of the rest.

**Example**

First, let's define some classes for example purposes, which may be trivialized versions of your current ones:

```
// This represents the frequency a loan would occur
public class LoanFrequency
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public LoanFrequency(int id, string value)
    {
        Id = id;
        Value = value;
    }
}

// This is a very basic example of a loan
public class Loan
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Frequency { get; set; }

    public Loan(string name, int frequency)
    {
        Name = name;
        Frequency = frequency;
    }
}
```

You don't need to set a specific default value for your frequencies if you are going to use it simply to set using a property from another object (i.e. a Loan). So you can define your `SelectList` within your Controller along with some values that will be passed to your View:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
        // Example loan frequencies
        ViewBag.LoanFrequencies = new SelectList(new LoanFrequency[]
        {
            new LoanFrequency(1, "Weekly"),
            new LoanFrequency(2, "Biweekly"),
            new LoanFrequency(3, "Semimonthly"),
            new LoanFrequency(4, "Monthly"),
            new LoanFrequency(5, "Bimonthly"),
            new LoanFrequency(6, "Quaterly"),
            new LoanFrequency(7, "Semiannually"),
            new LoanFrequency(8, "Annually")
        }, "Id", "Value");

        // Example loans to bind
        var loans = new Loan[]
        {
            new Loan("Weekly Loan", 1),
            new Loan("Monthly Loan", 4),
            new Loan("Birthday Loan", 8)
        };

        return View(loans);
}
```

Within your View, you would just need to ensure that your `asp-for` property points to the frequency-related property of your `Loan` object, and that the `asp-items` attribute points to your collection of frequencies:

```
@model YourExampleApplication.Models.Loan[]

<ul>
    @foreach (var loan in Model)
    {
        <li>
            @loan.Name
            <select asp-for="@loan.Frequency" asp-items="ViewBag.LoanFrequencies"></select>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

This should output something that looks like the following:

[image]

Notice that each of the `<select>` elements properly bound its selection to the corresponding value for the Frequency attribute from each of the loans passed into the View.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to programming with asp.net would you mind give me a sample code? I am still learning asp.net core.

Comment: I've added an example, hope it helps.

Comment: That will not bind when you submit the form (you cannot use a `foreach` loop - it generates `name` attributes that have no relation ship to the model - refer [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943))